# Swift lastobject equivalent

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What is swifts equivalent to

```
[[view.subviews] lastObject]
```

Ive tried

```
view.subviews.lastObject
```

but this is not a function that exists in swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does exist, but I think it has been renamed (they've done that to a lot of things in swift); try:

```
view.subviews.last
```

Comment: ive tried .last, but it does not allow me to fetch that elements size. It does something wierd aswell, it wants me to rename it .last? when i do .last.frame

Comment: last returns optional type. So, you might have to unwrap it or use conditional unwrapping.

Comment: Okay, i figured out how to typecast it, was just me being stupid :) For others wondering: var view = selv.view.last as UIView